# Cant add audio to phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, audio, media

I am trying to add audio to my app
Using a USB and Intel XDK it works fine but when I try it on my phone it doesn't work

I have tried

```
<audio autoplay loop>
<source src="/android_asset/www/background.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

,

```
<embed src="/android_asset/www/background.mp3" autostart="true" width="0" height="0">
</embed>
```

and

```
myMedia = new Media("/android_asset/www/background.mp3");
myMedia.play();
```

I tried them with and without '/android_asset/www/'.I have the media plugin installed for Phonegap too. Also, the third one stops all code after it from running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the files in your "webroot" for your app or a sub folder?  Which device/OS are you testing this on?  The HTML5 audio tag *should* work fine, but you may need different formats for each OS.

Comment: @IanMaffett They are in the 'www' folder and I am using Android KitKat

Comment: Any chance you can post a zip of your project somewhere? I'll be happy to test it.